# Xcode 9 export options how to specify provisioning profile

Tags: ios, jenkins, build, xcode9-beta

I am running the build using Jenkins and with Xcode 9 beta, I am getting an error with the profile. Here is the error that I am getting

> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Select a provisioning profile for the
>   "Default" build configuration in the project editor.}

Please let me know how can I resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting this too. No idea why though :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Manually generate and export the IPA file with Xcode, it will create a file name ExportOptions.plist in the exported folder, copy that file to workspace root folder
2. In Jenkin General build settings, uncheck "Pack application, build and sign .ipa?", and check "Generate Archive?"
3. Add an Execute cell like this: `xcodebuild -exportArchive \
    -archivePath "${WORKSPACE}/build/YourProject.xcarchive" \
    -exportPath "${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/archive" \
    -exportOptionsPlist "${WORKSPACE}/ExportOptions.plist"`
4. (optional) Setup again your next steps on upload IPA file if any.

Comment: Hi Tony, yes I got this working with a similar approach as you mentioned.